# ignore в gulp uncss

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, npm, scss

Ребят, задача такая, исключить класс .is-active (он генерируется js-кодом, но стили задаются в .scss файле) при проверке gulp-ом uncss. На данный момент данный класс удаляется...

```
gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return gulp.src("Full/scss/destinationStyles.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', '>5%', 'IE 7', 'IE 8', 'IE 9']}))
        .pipe(cleanCss({compatibility: "ie8"}))
        .pipe(combineMq({
            beautify: false
        }))
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ["Full/index.html"],
            ignore: [".is-active"]
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))

        .pipe(gulp.dest("Full/css"))

        .pipe(notify("Good job!"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload ({
            stream: true
        }))
});
```

Как правильно решить такую задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стилях укажите комментарий перед строкой, которая попадает под исключение. Ниже указываю пример на CSS. Для Saas понадобится комментарий, который не удаляется при компиляции.

```
/* uncss:ignore */
.selector1 {
    /* this rule will be ignored */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такое решение данной проблемы, таким образом класс .is-active ищет во всех файлах и игнорируется.

```
.pipe(uncss({
  html: ["Full/index.html"],
  ignore: [/\.is-active/]
}))
```